# repeat a .js file until it finished with imacros

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

I stop with my first javascript macros and hope someone can help me.
I want to extract 60 links from a website. After that, klick the next page button and start again. For example, i have 90 pages from where i want to extract links. i klick play, the links from the first site would be extractet, the next site is open, but the macro stop. so i mußt klick the play button 89 times again.

this is my code:

```
var jump =3;
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1" + "\n"; 
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=div ATTR=id:rhsAjax" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*/dp/* EXTRACT=href" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=R1 TYPE=h2 ATTR=class:a-size-base* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=R1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=class:a-color-price* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\Dokumente<SP>und<SP>Einstellungen\\blub\\Desktop FILE=24.11.14-var.csv" + "\n"; 

for(i=1;i<=238;i+=jump){
iimSet("i",i);
iimPlay(macro);
}
{
var macro2;
macro2 = "CODE:";
macro2 +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:pagnNextString" + "\n"; 
iimPlay(macro2);
}
```

it works fine, but i dont know the code to start it from the beginning.
I also tried to make 2 seperate .js files, and start it with iimplay from a third file, but the iimplay funktion only plays .iim files :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not to add another cycle to navigate with the ‘next page’ button automatically:

```
...
for (j = 1; j <= 90; j++) {
    for(i = 1; i <= 238; i += jump) {
        ...
    }
    {
    ...
    iimPlay(macro2);
    }
}
```